# skaffold is building infinite times after integrating my nextjs app

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, skaffold

I am building a microservice app with kubernetes and I am using skaffold, but the issue is when my nextjs frontend is added to skaffold, if I make any change in any of the services including my frontend service, it keeps building infinite times, anyone have any idea regarding why this is happening?

I integrated my company and tenant service and skaffold quickly rebuilds if I change any files, but after integrating my next app, no issue for the first build, then after that if I touch any files in any of the services, it keeps building infinite times

[my skaffold configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkiar.png)

[nextjs app packag.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIv6b.png)

[yaml configuration of my kubernetes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb36W.png)

Comment: I fixed it, It was because I mentioned the src in the skaffold configuration wrong